# Is there a better/faster way to fill one vector with contents of another (smaller) vector than using a for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, vector, fill

I'm trying to figure out a better solution to fill a vector with another vector whill avoiding loops. Is it even possible? Maybe using address range or something else?

This is my working code which does exactly what I need but slowly:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> Vec2i;

void Vec2DPrinter(Vec2i vec)
{
    size_t vec_h = vec.size();

    for (size_t y = 0; y < vec_h; y++)
    {
        size_t vec_w = vec.at(y).size();

        for (size_t x = 0; x < vec_w; x++)
        {
            std::cout << vec.at(y).at(x);
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void Vec2DFiller(Vec2i &dest, Vec2i src, int dest_x, int dest_y)
{
    int src_h = (int)src.size();

    // Loop to fill dest vector with elements of src vector at specific coords
    for (int y = 0; y < src_h; y++)
    {
        int src_w = (int)src.at(y).size();
        int dest_h = (int)dest.size();

        if ((y + dest_y) >= dest_h)
        {
            break;
        }

        if ((y + dest_y) < 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        int dest_w = (int)dest.at(y + dest_y).size();

        for (int x = 0; x < src_w; x++)
        {
            if (x + dest_x >= dest_w)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (x + dest_x < 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            dest.at(y + dest_y).at(x + dest_x) = src.at(y).at(x);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // This is just visual example (i know how to fill vectors)
    Vec2i dest =
    {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };

    Vec2i src =
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
    };

    std::cout << "Destination contents (before change):" << std::endl;
    Vec2DPrinter(dest);
    std::cout << "\nSurce contents:" << std::endl;
    Vec2DPrinter(src);

    // Destination coords
    int dest_x = 3;
    int dest_y = 4;

    // Key function to fill one vector with another
    Vec2DFiller(dest, src, dest_x, dest_y);

    std::cout << "\nDestination contents (after change):" << std::endl;
    Vec2DPrinter(dest);

    std::string exit = "";
    std::getline(std::cin, exit);

    return 0;
}
```

Key part:

```cpp
// Destination coords
int dest_x = 3;
int dest_y = 4;

int src_h = (int)src.size();

// Loop to fill dest vector with elements of src vector at specific coords
for (int y = 0; y < src_h; y++)
{
    int src_w = (int)src.at(y).size();
    int dest_h = (int)dest.size();

    if ((y + dest_y) >= dest_h)
    {
        break;
    }

    if ((y + dest_y) < 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    int dest_w = (int)dest.at(y + dest_y).size();

    for (int x = 0; x < src_w; x++)
    {
        if (x + dest_x >= dest_w)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (x + dest_x < 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        dest.at(y + dest_y).at(x + dest_x) = src.at(y).at(x);
    }
}
```

This is the best solution I could come with. (Not the same but similar. The original one has single but wide `if` statement so it wouldn't fit on a single line here so that is why I changed it a bit.)

The reason why I want to do this is pretty simple.
I'm doing this thousand times a second and on a bigger scale, that is why.

I was searching on the web and found things like `std::fill` and `std::copy` but none of them meets my requirements. (`std::fill` is not what I need and `std::copy` is an algorithm that consists of loop.)

Comment: Have you actually measured std::copy (after creating target vector with correct capacity). `std::copy` can outperform raw memcpy. When optimizing always profile an optimized release build, and then make educated decissions. (`std::copy` will use cpu vectorization when available)

Comment: SO is answering specific questions, not improving codes and algorthms. Your question might be more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might be surprised at how good compilers are, check your code on godbolt.org (compiler explorer). And have a look at this video [what has my compiler done for me lately, Matt Godbolt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4)

Comment: Just use `std::copy()` or one of the other standard methods  unless you can give us a proof those don't meet your requirements.

Comment: Compare variants here https://quick-bench.com/

Comment: Re: `int src_w = (int)src.at(y).size();` — you **know** that `y` is a valid index because you wrote the `for` loop to ensure that. Don’t waste time testing it every time it’s used. Just use `src[y]`.

Comment: @273K or [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Having a target of arbitrary size, no, not possible, if you count `std::copy` as using a loop. Even if you do `std::memcpy` given a large enough range to copy the os will need to touch multiple pages, i.e. use a loop, even if this loop is hidden behind a system call. (I mean you could of course use recursion, but I'd question the competence of any programmer doing this and considering their code good quality.)

Comment: Looks like that `std::copy` is really faster. The problem was that when I was trying it I was doing it wrong. I still need to learn a lot.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm sorry. Maybe I don't unerstand it clearly. What do you mean by `src[y]`?
You mean `src[y].size()`?

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I need to ignore certain numbers when doing `std::copy()`. For example when having source vector with numbers like 1, 3, 7, 9 and copy entire vector but elements containing number 9. I have an algorithm for this but it is using loops too.

Comment: `src[y]` rather than `src.at(y)`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh that. I didn't realise it. I know this but maybe I wasn't paying attention. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all performance questions, the solution is going to depend heavily on the hardware and software being used and the particulars of the test conditions. In this case, for example, the dataset size is relevant.

With that caveat, I was able to improve the performance by over `4x` on my platform (M1, MacOSX, clang). Your mileage will vary. I moved the conditional checks out of the inner loop and used `std::copy` for the actual work. For larger dataset sizes, I suspect the speedup will be greater.

I used the [timer](https://github.com/cpp-core/timer) library for measuring performance.

Performance could be improved further by using a native 2D storage structure like a matrix or `std::mdspan` instead of a `std::vector` of `std::vector`.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "core/timer/timer.h"

using std::cout, std::endl;

typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> Vec2i;

void Vec2DPrinter(Vec2i vec) {
    size_t vec_h = vec.size();
    for (size_t y = 0; y < vec_h; y++) {
        size_t vec_w = vec.at(y).size();
        for (size_t x = 0; x < vec_w; x++)
            std::cout << vec.at(y).at(x);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void Vec2DFiller(Vec2i &dest, Vec2i src, int dest_x, int dest_y) {
    int src_h = (int)src.size();

    // Loop to fill dest vector with elements of src vector at specific coords
    for (int y = 0; y < src_h; y++) {
        int src_w = (int)src.at(y).size();
        int dest_h = (int)dest.size();

        if ((y + dest_y) >= dest_h)
            break;

        if ((y + dest_y) < 0)
            continue;

        int dest_w = (int)dest.at(y + dest_y).size();

        for (int x = 0; x < src_w; x++) {
            if (x + dest_x >= dest_w)
                break;

            if (x + dest_x < 0)
                continue;

            dest.at(y + dest_y).at(x + dest_x) = src.at(y).at(x);
        }
    }
}

void Vec2DFiller2(Vec2i &dest, const Vec2i& src, int dest_x, int dest_y) {
    int ylen = std::min(src.size(), dest.size() > dest_y ? dest.size() - dest_y : 0);
    if (ylen == 0)
        return;

    int xlen = std::min(src.at(0).size(), dest.at(0).size() - dest_x);
    if (xlen == 0)
        return;

    for (auto ydx = 0; ydx < ylen; ++ydx) {
        auto& ydest = dest.at(ydx + dest_y);
        const auto& ysrc = src.at(ydx);
        std::copy(ysrc.data(), ysrc.data() + xlen, ydest.data() + dest_x);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // This is just visual example (i know how to fill vectors)
    Vec2i dest =
    {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };

    Vec2i src =
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
    };

    std::cout << "Destination contents (before change):" << std::endl;
    Vec2DPrinter(dest);
    std::cout << "\nSurce contents:" << std::endl;
    Vec2DPrinter(src);

    // Destination coords
    int dest_x = 3;
    int dest_y = 4;

    // Key function to fill one vector with another
    auto ns = core::timer::Timer().run(1'000'000, [&]() {
        Vec2DFiller(dest, src, dest_x, dest_y);
    }).elapsed_per_iteration();
    cout << ns << " ns / op" << endl;

    ns = core::timer::Timer().run(1'000'000, [&]() {
        Vec2DFiller2(dest, src, dest_x, dest_y);
    }).elapsed_per_iteration();
    cout << ns << " ns / op" << endl;

    std::cout << "\nDestination contents (after change):" << std::endl;
    Vec2DPrinter(dest);

    return 0;
}
```

### Relevant Output

```
142.167 ns / op
30.4702 ns / op
```

Comment: Wow. That is pretty impressive.
I'm on Windows but I've tried your sollution and here are the results:

repeat 1 000 000 times
Time elapsed (1): 33.2788s.
Time elapsed (2): 3.92806s.

It is almost 10 times faster.
Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it.

I'm also doing similar thing but with "vector to semi 2D string (like 00000\n00000\n00000\n etc.)" with my weird algorithm, but I will do it somehow.

Comment: There is only thing that I'm not sure about. If it is possible to use `std::copy()` and also ignore certain numbers.

Comment: @skrovno_CZ No it isn't.  `std::for_each` could handle that, and can be parallelised.

Comment: @PaulSanders Oh ok. Well I was trying to do parallel loops but always ended up with results slower than regular `for`. I'm still trying to learn threads and stuff. So I will do it maybe later.